# How to enable an uwp application to receive notification from the Microsoft store

Tags: c#, uwp, push-notification, store

I have a desktop UWP app published on the Microsoft Store and I want to send notifications to users. I did exactly the same thing as described in this question and it didn't work. The Microsoft Store does not show the app in the list for creating a notification. Any suggestion?

[Microsoft Store Engagement Services - Dev Center Push Notifications UWP C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938804/microsoft-store-engagement-services-dev-center-push-notifications-uwp-c-sharp)

[image]

In the App.xaml.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement;

public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

    prcEnableNotification();
}

private async void prcEnableNotification()
{
    StoreServicesEngagementManager manager = StoreServicesEngagementManager.GetDefault();
    await manager.RegisterNotificationChannelAsync();
}

protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnActivated(args);

    if (args is ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs)
    {
        var toastActivationArgs = args as ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs;

        StoreServicesEngagementManager engagementManager = StoreServicesEngagementManager.GetDefault();
        string originalArgs = engagementManager.ParseArgumentsAndTrackAppLaunch(toastActivationArgs.Argument);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you please check what's the result of manager.RegisterNotificationChannelAsync? Does it show an error code? Another thing is that have you associated your app to the store?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT That is exactly the problem. I cannot associate the application because it does not appear in the list of available applications when creating a notification. In the Partner Center, the following message appears "You must configure your application to receive notifications using the Microsoft Store Services SDK."

Comment: I'm confused, do you mean that it failed when you tried to associate your app?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, I'm sorry for not being clear. The question is: my app is available on the Microsoft Store, but when I try to create a new Notification in the Partner Center, my app does not appear in the listbox. The listbox remains empty, despite changes that were made to the application code. I include an image of the Partner Center page.

Comment: Yeah, I know that you have an app in the Store. What I want to know is that have you associated the app successfully with your project from Visual Studio? The association process is that right-click on the project and choose to publish, then select associate your app.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, Yes, the Visual Studio project has been associated with the application on the Microsoft Store. I made the code change, generated the packages and submitted it to the store.

Comment: Please open a free [support ticket](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support/) about this issue so that the team could check if there is an issue with this process

Comment: Thank you, @RoyLi-MSFT. I'll do that.